Is there a good definition of free energy of a subsystem?
Consider the $L$ by $L$ 2d Ising model with $\beta H = -K \sum_{\langle i j \rangle} \sigma_i \sigma_j$. I'm interested in the canonical ensemble.
I can define the free energy of the whole system as $F = \frac{-\log(Z)}{\beta}$. This has certain natural properties, including corresponding to $\langle E \rangle - T S$, where $S$ is the usual entropy of a probability distribution.
Is there a nice way to define $F$ for a subsystem of the above system? In particular, I'm curious if there is a definition with the property that the total free energy would be the sum of the subsystem free energies of a disjoint covering of the system by subsystems.

I mean, one of the standard derivations of the canonical ensemble is as a subsystem of a larger (normally mocrocanonical, but that is not a major factor) system. The only complications is if there are additional conserved qualities that the full system does not exchange with its environment, but subsystems exchange with each other (eg particle number)

As written in the comment section, you can always just carve out a subsystem that you are interested in, and then define the distribution on it, to define an effective subsystem Hamiltonian. That's how the canonical ensemble is defined anyways.
One way to explicitly do this is to calculate the subsystem energy with $H_{\mathrm{sub}}$ that is a proper restriction of $H$ to the subset of spins which we denote as $\sigma_\mathrm{sub}$.
\begin{equation}
Z_{\mathrm{sub}}:= \sum_{\mathrm{sub.~config. ~\sigma}} e^{-\beta H_{\mathrm{sub}}(\sigma_{\mathrm{sub}})}
\end{equation}
The subsystem free energy could now just be taken as $F_\mathrm{sub}:=-\frac{1}{\beta}\log Z_{\mathrm{sub}}$ and it satisfies the relation
\begin{equation}
\langle E_{\mathrm{sub}}\rangle -TS_\mathrm{sub}=F_\mathrm{sub}
\end{equation}
where $S_\mathrm{sub}$ is defined as the Shannon entropy of the marginal distribution for $\sigma_\mathrm{sub}$ with the canonical distribution.
Dividing the entire system into pieces will admit relations as $\sum F_\mathrm{sub}=F$ as long as the boundary between those regions are negligible. For example, if you divide the entire system into 9 pieces like a tic-tac-toe, the boundary only scales as $6L=O(L)$ opposed to the entire system scaling as $O(L^2)$, and is thus negligible in the thermodynamic sense.
